# Onion Architecture - Where to put complex database query lookup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, separation-of-concerns, n-tier-architecture, onion-architecture

I've been struggling with a design decision and was hoping for some feedback.

Architecture summary:
ASP.NET MVC WebAPI solution with a SPA frontend written in KnockoutJS and Entity Framework hooked up to a SQL DB.

The problem: we have two entities that pull a value (Rate) from a somewhat complex lookup table. The lookup table filters down to a distinct option based on 5 parameters, all 5 parameter values can be determined based on properties on each entity or a related table.  On top of this look up value, both entities can have "Rate Modifiers" which can add another small amount to this lookup value.

The question: where should we put this lookup logic if we would like this calculated rate to be available anytime we use these two entities?

1. Service layer: have a service to request these entities, request
   the entities from the Data (Infrastructure) layer repository, then
   make individual calls back to the data layer to get the computed
   rate
2. Data layer: inside the data layer repository get all the
   entities and lookup the values there within the repository
3. UI layer: just send the entities to the UI layer and then have web
       services to retrieve the rates for the 5 parameters
4. DB: Create a view in the db for these entities that does all the
   rate lookup logic for us in the db
5. Other suggestions?

I see advantages and disadvantages to all of these options and none of them feel quite right to me.  Option 3 feels like it's the cleanest, but is probably the least performant and is the most chatty.  options 2/4 seem messy putting business-like logic in the data layer and option 1 feels a little over complex and inefficient.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: If I understand your requirement correctly, how about an IQueryable extension?  If all of the parameters are already known then your extension can return an IQueryable<Lookup>.  Whether you use the repository pattern, service layer, or CQRS(my favorite), you should have access to your DbContext where you could execute your first query with the extension.  Get it's value and then make your second query to your two entities.  Now if you want this to be some sort of calculated field that is available when the entity is materialized, just add a property, but that sounds really expensive.

Comment: All data queries should be in the data layer.

Answer (score 2):

1. If seperation of concerns or keeping everything clean  is your concern, then it is  best to keep it in the Service layer. Just as you suggested ,having the UI layer call the service layer which in turn calls the datalayer.  The service layer is where the business logic usually lies. This is the ideal situation though.
2. However, if speed is your concern I think  it is better to keep things in the DB layer probably as a stored procedure. In my experience this performs really well. But generally it is best not to spread business logic across layers.

Whatever solution you use , it is best to choose based on what your priority is - seperation of concerns or speed ,etc.

Do let us know what you went with.

Comment: I agree, I think most of these decisions come down to balancing the value gained in each aspect (performance, maintainability, etc).  Thanks for your input.